# Nested Lookup and filtering

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have below collections

**User**

```
[
{
  id : 'acd-1234',
  name : 'some name',
  profile_id : 1,
  is_graduate: true, 
  children: [
    { class: 'User', id: 'abcd-123'},
    { class: 'User', id: 'bcd-33'}
  ]
},
{
  id: 'abcd-123',
  name : 'jhon',
  profile_id : 2
  is_graduate: true, 
},
{
  id: 'bcd-123',
  name : 'jhon due',
  profile_id : 3,
  is_graduate: false 
}
]
```

**Profile**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    address: 'some address'  
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    address: 'some other address'  
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    address: 'some other other address'  
  }

]
```

Final Output that i need is ( Parent with only graduate children)

```
[
  {
    id: 'acd-1234',
    name: 'some name',
    is_graduate: true, 
    profile : {
       id: 1,
       address: "some address"
    },
    children: [
       {
         id: "abcd-123",
         name: "jhon",
         is_graduate: true, 
         profile: {
           id: 2,
           address: "some other address" 
         }
       }
    ] 
  }
]
```

Where i am really stuck is

1. Making nested lookup. Showing profile with all the children
2. applying filtering on the childrens

Below error from mongo is not allowing me to use pipeline with localField
`$lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "profile",
            let: { id: "$profile_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$id", "$$id"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "profile"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$profile" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            let: {
                id: { $ifNull: ["$children.id", []] }
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $in: ["$id", "$$id"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "profile",
                        localField: "profile_id",
                        foreignField: "id",
                        as: "profile"
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$profile" }
            ],
            as: "children"
        }
    }
]);
```

If you want to show only non empty `children` then add below `$match` stage after last `$lookup`:

```js
{
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $gt: [{ $size: "$children" }, 0]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It solves the problem. However when i am running this query with about 30k users its taking to much time. Obiviously actual collections have many more fields and lookups(i also have necessary indexes). I doubt that it is because of we are joining user with user. Can we somehow have two separate stages one for just lookup with children and  then filter and perform nested lookup  with user in next stage(it will reduce the amount of data passing through the stages).

Comment: S u are right. U can add `$match` stage in various places to filter out unwanted documents getting into next stage.

Comment: I am aware about match thing. but Looks like only this particular join (user*user) is taking most of the time. So do you any suggestions. Like how can we separte out the JOINING part and do lookup and filtering in next stage.